# When must CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization be called?

Tags: ios, background, location, cllocationmanager

I have an application that I'm working on that needs to be able to get the background location of the user and update the server.  The problem is that the only way I can get it to work is when I requestAlwaysAuthorization before application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions finishes.

If I request it later, the app doesn't ever call my location delegate callback.  Is this a known issue and if so, how can I work around it.

The desire is for it to be an optional feature that is configured on our server.  Some users will belong to a group that will have this feature enabled.  This requires me to have our user login first, so I can see if this feature is enabled.  That is the problem for me.  I'd like to only prompt for the location permission if we really intend to use it.

I've tested with apps like Strava and they are able to delay requesting the location permission until you start recording an activity.  The docs don't mention anything about when to request it, except that it has to happen before you start updating the location.  This should be possible, but I'm missing something.

```
// Methods from AppDelegate...
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    ...
    // Normal initialization code goes here
    ...

    // Requesting alwaysAuthorization here works
    LocationManager.shared.requestPermission()

    return true
}

func handleAfterLoginEvent() {
    // Requesting alwaysAuthorization here, instead of in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't work
    LocationManager.shared.requestPermission()
}

func handleServerPushRequestForLocation() {
    // Called when push notification is received.
    LocationManager.shared.reportCurrentLocation()
}


// End AppDelegate methods

public class LocationManager {

    public static let shared = LocationManager()

    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var delegate = LocationDelegate()

    init() {
        locationManager.delegate = delegate
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    }

    deinit {
        locationManager.delegate = nil
    }

    public func requestPermission() {
        print("requestPermission called")
        let status: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        LocationManager.print(status: status)
        if status != .authorizedAlways {
            print("Requesting always authorization for LocationManager")
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    public func reportCurrentLocation() {
        print("reportCurrentLocation called")

        guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
            print("Skipping location update. Location services aren't enabled.")
            return
        }

        print("requestLocation")
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    public static func print(status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
            case .notDetermined         : print("LocationManager: notDetermined")
            case .authorizedWhenInUse   : print("LocationManager: authorizedWhenInUse")
            case .authorizedAlways      : print("LocationManager: authorizedAlways")
            case .restricted            : print("LocationManager: restricted")
            case .denied                : print("LocationManager: denied")
            default                     : print("LocationManager: unknown")
        }
    }

}

public class LocationDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager didFailWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLocation = locations.last
        print("LocationManager lat: \(currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude.description ?? "nil"), long: \(currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude.description ?? "nil"), horizontalAccuracy: \(currentLocation?.horizontalAccuracy.debugDescription ?? "nil"), time: \(currentLocation?.timestamp.debugDescription ?? "nil")")

        postNotification(currentLocation)
    }

    public func locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("LocationManager locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates")
    }

    public func locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("LocationManager locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates")
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        LocationManager.print(status: status)
    }

    private func postNotification(_ currentLocation: CLLocation?) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "New location reported"
        content.body = "LocationManager lat: \(currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude.description ?? "nil"), long: \(currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude.description ?? "nil"), horizontalAccuracy: \(currentLocation?.horizontalAccuracy.debugDescription ?? "nil"), time: \(currentLocation?.timestamp.debugDescription ?? "nil")"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = "notify-new-location"

        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "notify-new-location", content: content, trigger: nil)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look right. You have implemented a singleton but you never reference `.shared`. The situation you describe isn't normal. It sounds to me like an object has gone out of scope as is being released. Also you need to handle the case that the user may only grant "when in use" even though you ask for "always". A better check is to see if status is `.notDetermined` rather than not equal to always.

Comment: I updated my code to reference the shared instance.  That was a typo when I was simplifying my code base for this question.  Like I said previously, this code works correctly when I request permission at the end of application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  It doesn't ever return any locations if I just delay the first location permission request until after the user logs in.

Comment: When/how is `handleAfterLoginEvent` called?  Is that function called on the main queue?

Comment: No, it receives a SwiftEventBus event on a background thread.  I think you were right though about scope.  I created a LocationManager instance in my AppDelegate and set the shared instance to it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  After doing that I was able to request the permission in the login and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is important that a `CLLocationManager` is instantiated from a thread that is associated with a `RunLoop`, otherwise delegate methods will not be called.  One way of ensuring this is to instantiate it from the main queue.

When `handleAfterLoginEvent` is the first reference to your singleton, the location manager instance is instantiated from a thread without a `RunLoop` and delegate methods aren't called.

You can either instantiate the singleton earlier, from the main queue, or explicitly dispatch the creation onto the main queue.

Note that the user has the option of denying location permission or granting "when in use" even though you asked for "always". A better check in your code might be for `status == .notDetermined` rather than `!= .authorizedAlways`